# trying to loop through an array where the elements are object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm wondering why the code outputs false when you can see in the object that Wednesday = 34. I think i might have problems with changing the i variable.

```
var lookup = [{"Monday" : 12}, {"Wednesday" : 34},{"Thursday" : 0},{"Saturday" : 56} ]
// console.log(lookup[1]["Wednesday"] == 34) // prints out true
function ami(day, num){
    var a;
    for(var i = 0; i < lookup.length; i++){
        if(lookup[i][day] == num || 
            day == "Tuesday" && num >95 ||
             day == "Friday" && num %2 == 0 || 
             day == "Sunday" && num == 666 ||
             day == "Sunday" && num == -666){
            a = true
        }else{
            a = false
        }

     }
     return a;

}
console.log(ami("Wednesday", 34))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting the value of `a` with each iteration of the `for` loop. In essence, what you are doing is checking the last item of the `lookup` array, since the previous results are always overwritten.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve with the conditions, but this could be what you need:

```
function ami(day, num){
    for(var i = 0; i < lookup.length; i++){
        if(lookup[i][day] == num || 
            day == "Tuesday" && num >95 ||
            day == "Friday" && num %2 == 0 || 
            day == "Sunday" && num == 666 ||
            day == "Sunday" && num == -666){
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this led me to my desired results I originally had true and false not `a` variable. originally  I put the return false before the closing brackets that is right before the return false in the code you've shown. why couldn't I put the return false in the for loop when i was able to put return true. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When your code reaches i=1, a gets indeed set to true. But after that the loop is allowed to continue, so when i gets incremented to 2, a gets set to false again.

You can fix this by returning from the function as soon as you determine the return value should be true:

```js
var lookup = [{"Monday" : 12}, {"Wednesday" : 34},{"Thursday" : 0},{"Saturday" : 56} ]
function ami(day, num){
    for(var i = 0; i < lookup.length; i++){
        if(lookup[i][day] == num || 
            day == "Tuesday" && num >95 ||
             day == "Friday" && num %2 == 0 || 
             day == "Sunday" && num == 666 ||
             day == "Sunday" && num == -666){
            return true;
        }
     }
}
console.log(ami("Wednesday", 34));
```

You can simplify the code even further if you use an ordinary object as your lookup table:

```js
var lookup = {"Monday" : 12, "Wednesday" : 34, "Thursday" : 0, "Saturday" : 56};
function ami(day, num){
    return (lookup[day] == num || 
        day == "Tuesday" && num >95 ||
         day == "Friday" && num %2 == 0 || 
         day == "Sunday" && num == 666 ||
         day == "Sunday" && num == -666);
}
console.log(ami("Wednesday", 34));
```

Comment: I'm curious to know what happens when  a condition inside a for loop  returns false. will the  loop end before the ending condition has been met? is this topic probably the reason why i was getting the unexpected results?   i put in the `a` variable stuff because the way i had the Booleans being returned  wasn't working out, so i decide to try something new.

Comment: Yes, you can leave the loop by using a `return` statement (which ends the function the loop is in) or a `break` statement, which only ends the loop it is in. There is also the `continue` statement, which skips the rest of the loop body for the current iteration.

However, this has nothing to do with a condition evaluating to false. If you want to exit the loop prematurely, you have to explicitly tell the JavaScript interpreter to do so (or a function you call has to throw an exception which you do not catch).

Answer (score 0):

A `Array.some()` should do it.

```js
var lookup = [{ "Monday": 12 }, { "Wednesday": 34 }, { "Thursday": 0 }, { "Saturday": 56 }];
function ami(day, num) {
    return lookup.some(function (a) { return a[day] === num; }) ||
        day == "Tuesday" && num > 95 ||
        day == "Friday" && num % 2 == 0 ||
        day == "Sunday" && num == 666 ||
        day == "Sunday" && num == -666
}
document.write(ami("Wednesday", 34));
```

The other possibillity is to optimise the lookup array to an object with more than one property, like

```
var lookup = { "Monday": 12, "Wednesday": 34, "Thursday": 0, "Saturday": 56 };
```

The other version is this. I took your code and changed the behaviour of the condition and the loop condition as well. So the given conditions are first evaluated and then if necessary the iteration over the array. The variable `a` is taken as well as indicator to stop the iteration as well as the return value.

```js
var lookup = [{ "Monday": 12 }, { "Wednesday": 34 }, { "Thursday": 0 }, { "Saturday": 56 }];
function ami(day, num) {
    var a = false;
    if (day == "Tuesday" && num > 95 ||
        day == "Friday" && num % 2 == 0 ||
        day == "Sunday" && num == 666 ||
        day == "Sunday" && num == -666) {
        a = true;
    }
    for (var i = 0; !a && i < lookup.length; i++) {
        a = lookup[i][day] == num;
    }
    return a;
}
document.write(ami("Wednesday", 34));
```